# Scroll to images that uploaded from computer

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I would be very happy to help
I uploaded many pictures from my computer and I want there to be an option for scrolling to pictures.
my code in html:

```html
<div>
    <input accept=".jpeg,.jpg ,.png" type="file" class="file-input" multiple="multiple" (change)="selectFile($event)"
        #fileUpload>
    <mat-card>
        <button mat-icon-button class="upload-btn" (click)="fileUpload.click()">
            <mat-icon><span class="material-icons">add</span></mat-icon>
        </button>
    </mat-card>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="image-box" *ngFor="let image of Images ; let i = index">
        <img src={{image.url}} alt="Img" style=" width: 100px; height: 100px;">
      <button class="btn"`enter code here` mat-icon-button (click)="removeImage(i)">
          <mat-icon><span class="material-icons">delete_outline</span></mat-icon>
      </button>``
    </div>  
</div>
```

**This is how it looks in practice**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR2yu.png)

**How do I make the pictures appear to me with a scroll?
Like the following picture:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgL9v.png)

I would be very happy to help, I am new in Angular :) !!!!
Thank you !!!

Comment: Can you please add js to your code?

Comment: If i understood correctly then you want to show images in a horizontal row with scroll.
To achieve that you can use display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap; in css.
And at then add button to same container to which you are adding display flex